# Putting the button in the footer area of the modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone help me on my problem wherein the two buttons should be on the footer side which is at the bottom side of the modal. Just focus on the two buttons, do not mind the other contents hehe. I did some adjustments of the modal height because I am trying to copy the height of the modal design for us.

Herewith is the attached jfiddle to fully elaborate my problem. Thanks! https://jsfiddle.net/wqj9x0md/

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn m-2 btn-primary add-order myBtn">ADD ORDER</button>


<!-- Trigger/Open The Add Order -->
<div id="modal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <span class="close float-end">&times;</span></h3>


      <form action="" method="">

        <div class="row title">
          <div class="col">Order</div>
          <div class="col">Pieces</div>
          <div class="col">Price</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row add-order-info text-center">
          <div class="col">

            <div class="dropdown">
              <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                Select...
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Laptop</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Computer</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">IPAD</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="" id="">
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="" id="">
          </div>
        </div>




        <div id="formsContainer">
          <div style="display: none;" id="form1">

            <form action="" method="" id="add-order-form">
              <div class="row add-order-info text-center">
                <div class="col">

                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                      Select...
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Laptop</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Computer</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">IPAD</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col">
                  <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                  <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="button" value="Add Child" onclick="addForm();" id="add-button">
          &plus;
        </button>

        <div class="center my-3">
          <div class="row fw-bold">
            <div class="col-4 total" style="color: #116657;">TOTAL</div>
            <div class="col-3">450</div>
          </div>
        </div>

           <div class="d-inline d-flex justify-content-center
           align-items-center">
          <button class="btn-add-order" type="submit">Add Order</button>
          <button class="btn-cancel-order">Cancel</button>
        </div>

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal END -->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div element containing your `Add order` and `Cancel` buttons:

```
<div class="d-inline d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" ...
```

Could be positioned absolute since the modal already has `position:relative;`

So if you style it like this:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 1em;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
```

You'll have it centered and with a gap of `1em` from its parent bottom border.

***BUT***...of course I forgot to take into account the fact that position absolute was going to detach the element from the flow and it won't occupy space anymore.

So as you pointed out in comments there's the chance some content will overlap.

There's a solution while still keeping the absolute positioning strategy but I don't like it indeed.

You could put a padding bottom on that containing block, thick as much as the height of your button stripe.

But it's very annoying because you should move the `position: relative;` to your `.modal-content` instead of your `.modal-body` and you should have it styled also with `padding-bottom: 4em;`

It will work as far as I tried in your jsfiddle but I'm the first one saying there must be a better way.

Comment: This can be helpful but when I add a form through the bottom, it will overlap the total and the two buttons

Comment: I made an edit with a solution to circumvent the problem that worked. But I'm the first saying I don't like it

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look at the code you will see that there is a class called " modal-body" and the content inside of it is the body, if you want to display the buttons in the footer you will have to add a div with class "modal-footer" u can tell that it will display the content in the footer by its name haha

here's the full code of the modal :

```
  <div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
  <span class="close float-end">&times;</span>


  <form action="" method="">

    <div class="row title">
      <div class="col">Order</div>
      <div class="col">Pieces</div>
      <div class="col">Price</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row add-order-info text-center">
      <div class="col">

        <div class="dropdown">
          <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
            Select...
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Laptop</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Computer</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">IPAD</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
      </div>
    </div>




    <div id="formsContainer">
      <div style="display: none;" id="form1">

        <form action="" method="" id="add-order-form">
          <div class="row add-order-info text-center">
            <div class="col">

              <div class="dropdown">
                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                  Select...
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Laptop</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Computer</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">IPAD</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" name="" id="">
            </div>

            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" name="" id="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" value="Add Child" onclick="addForm();" id="add-button">
      &plus;
    </button>

    <div class="center my-3">
      <div class="row fw-bold">
        <div class="col-4 total" style="color: #116657;">TOTAL</div>
        <div class="col-3">450</div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </form>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <div class="d-inline d-flex justify-content-center
       align-items-center">
    <button class="btn-add-order" type="submit">Add Order</button>
    <button class="btn-cancel-order">Cancel</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I also tried that but it doesn't work when you configure the height of of the modal-body

Comment: tell me exactly what do u want to do with that modal, because I didn't fully understand what do you wanna do with it so I can adapt the code to what u need

Comment: I just want the two buttons on the bottom part of the modal. Kindly look at the jsfiddle for you to understand more hehe.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can test now the buttons are in the footer and whatever you have in height won't impact them